# The duck is listening without hearing

Tags: bug, quack-overflow

I click on the duck, it asks me whether I have a microphone. I do, but click "No". It shows "Quack Overflow is listening…" and the Siri-like wavy lines.

So, why is it listening to me even though it can't hear what I say? (I think it doesn't because when I say something, the wavy lines don't change their movement).

> macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
>
> Safari: 11.0.1 (13604.3.5)

Comment: Because rubber duck debugging is about you listening to *yourself* explain the problem?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, well, I was hoping the duck would say this to me after having detected input from a mic or something... Then what's the point of the whole microphone thing?...I mean, it turns out that it doesn't matter whether I have a mic or not, so the duck's question about this is rather pointless.

Comment: Not only is the duck "listening without hearing" but it is also "writing songs that voices never share" when it displays "Quack".

Comment: @Paul, it also dares disturb the sound of silence with the quacks!

Comment: Have you tried explaining the issue you're having to the duck?

Comment: @Jaydles, I'm aware of this debugging method, but I prefer to explain it to myself out loud as the duck cannot answer, unfortunately.

Comment: Your answer is written on the subway walls and tenement halls.

Comment: And no one dared disturb the sound of meta.

Comment: The duckie said, "You do not know / How it works Quack Overflow / Hear my quacks that I might nag you / Take my words that I might help you" / Rubber ducking, the answer came to me / It answered in the quacks of duckies

Answer (score 16):

Quack Overflow is a little hard of hearing. Her ears were damaged when she was flying too close to a hunter when his shotgun discharged. Also, she is just a bit paranoid of microphones so we never enable yours no matter what you click.

Comment: Why have that choice though? I legit thought clicking "Yes" would result in some magic or the duck searching for SO questions based on what I say...

Comment: Because people would expect the choice and the fact that we tell you it's "magic" is kinda a clue that it's not real, right?

Comment: [Yay for copy and paste!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308597/355458)

Comment: _Her ears were damaged_ . has SO considered taking poor ducky to a Vet

Answer (score 2):

With the magic of internet, the duck can listen anyway !

Comment: Whoever downvoted, this message is displayed when you click 'I don't have a microphone'. Apparently OP missed it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, no, it doesn’t! At least for me, it goes straight to “Quack Overflow is listening”. (I checked this multiple times). That’s probably why I don’t get the point of the duck.

Comment: @ForceBru Huh. Here is the pic: https://i.imgur.com/ySWkofH.png